# im getting this error when i opened android studio :The file name must end with .xml

Tags: android-studio, gradle, sdk

android studio was working last night.i just save project and closed android studio.When i opened again im getting this error.how to fix it

```
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\drawable\drawable.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\drawable-v24\drawable-v24.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\font\font.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml, .ttf, .ttc or .otf
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\layout\layout.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\mipmap-anydpi-v26\mipmap-anydpi-v26.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\mipmap-hdpi.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\mipmap-mdpi.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\mipmap-xhdpi.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\mipmap-xxhdpi.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\mipmap-xxxhdpi.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
 D:\BilgiYarismasi\app\src\main\res\values\values.exe: Error: The file name must end with .xml
 :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
```

my gradle
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "myid"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
  "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `.exe` from all your drawable folders extension. It will then build successfully